# django form.is_valid is failing & not saving the form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

My account model automatically creates when user creates a new user account & only user value is added to that model, rest remains empty!
i am trying to make the user update or add more info in their account model but the is.valid() is failing in views & not saving the form. what went wrong & how to fix it?

Models.py

```py
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="profile_images", default="default.jpg")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Forms.py

```py
class accountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = profile
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            # 'fields': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}),
            'profile_img': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'inputGroupFile04'}),
            'bio': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'location': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Location'}),

        }
```

views.py

```py
def account(request):
    Profile = profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = accountForm(instance=Profile)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = accountForm(request.POST, instance=Profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("sign_in")

    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "account.html", context)
```

Comment: What kind of error message do you get? And your `location` has `blank=True` but no `null=True` set.

Comment: i don't get any error messages. it just renders me to the account.html page. meaning it doesn't go through form.is_valid(), & form.save()

Comment: since you are handling user pictures you should add form = forms.PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
(but i am not sure this is related to fixing your problem)

Comment: nah bro, it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

I would impliment some error handling in your view. You have an

`if form.is_valid:`
statement but no else.  That's why errors are not showing up on the page

Usually when this happens to me I drop a debugger statement right after the call to .is_valid()

`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`

Then in the resulting terminal I will type `form.errors` and you should see what went wrong

Comment: This is helpful advice but its not an answer that will fix the OP problem as stated. This would be better as a comment to the question.

Comment: yeah, i missed that part more often. thnks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in order to upload files, you’ll need to make sure that your  element correctly defines the **enctype** as **"multipart/form-data"** in your form tag:

```html
#templates file
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">
```

Secondly, add **request.FILES** to `form = accountForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=Profile)`

You can read more about this from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cleaned_data` to save the form.

Try this view:

views.py

```py
def account(request):
    profile_instance = profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = accountForm(instance=profile_instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = accountForm(request.POST, instance=profile_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            bio = request.POST.get('bio')
            profile_img = request.POST.get('profile_img')
            location = request.POST.get('location')

            profile.objects.create(
                user=user, bio=bio, profile_img=profile_img, location=location)
            return redirect("sign_in")
    else:
        form = accountForm()

    return render(request, "home/account.html", {'form': form})
```

Make sure, you are logged in and `profile` model does not contain two same users for working of above code, as you have made it `Foreignkey`.

> `Note:` Models are written in `PascalCase` not `smallcase`, so it will be better if you name it as `Profile` instead of <s>`profile`</s>. Same goes for forms, better if you write `AccountForm`, or more better `ProfileForm` instead of <s>`accountForm`</s>.

---

---

---

Try below code, in which profile will be created directlty.

models.py

```py
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields are same...
```

In real scenario, it will be better to make `user` a `OneToOneField` in `Profile` model, as one person can only have one profile, I assumed you are creating users' profile first time, rather than updating the existing profiles, so I'll not use
`instance` in form.

views.py

```py
def account(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = accountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password1')
            bio = request.POST.get('bio')
            profile_img = request.POST.get('profile_img')
            location = request.POST.get('location')
            created_user = User.objects.create(
                username=username, password=password)

            profile.objects.create(
                user=created_user, bio=bio, profile_img=profile_img, location=location)
            return redirect('sign_in')
    else:
        form = accountForm()

    return render(request, "home/account.html", {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```py
class accountForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        p1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        p2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if p1 != p2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Both the passwords must match')

    class Meta:
        model = profile
        fields = ['username', 'password1',
                  'password2', 'profile_img', 'bio', 'location']
        widgets = {
            # 'fields': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}),
            'profile_img': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'inputGroupFile04'}),
            'bio': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'location': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Location'}),

        }
```

It will create new users' profile directly, with password validation and those users also relate to `User` model, so you'll not get the error of `the  field user in profile model must be an user instance`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyones suggestions but i figured out what was the issue here. sorry for not providing the html codes bcz i didn't added forms.user tag there . so request.POST wasn't providing the user. there are two ways to fix this. you can use onetoone relation in models.py which will not necesarily need you to choose users. the next one is more efficient that is, in forms. py hide the user form by:

```
class accountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = profile
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            user': forms.hiddenInput(),
            'profile_img': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'inputGroupFile04'}),
            'bio': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'location': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Location'}),

        }
```

then, add the user in views.py through INITIAL like :

```
def account(request):
    form = accountForm(initial=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = accountForm(request.POST, initial = request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("sign_in")

    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "account.html", context)
```

if you want to update it, use instance instead of initial & provide the profile there

Comment: Have you looked at my second solution, and do you know what does `form` have? The `form` have whole html form, you can print it through `print(form)`, you'll be able to see whole html form, so it will be better to save from cleaned_data, it has only particular field, and that too its value, and by using `create()` method on any Model, it doesn't require `save()` to be called.